# How to fix 'display class' and 'grid classes'?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am building an album with bootstrap 'Cards', I am trying to do two things:

**1) Have the cards expand fully for small screen sizes `col-sm-12`?**

**2) Hide an element for small screen sizes `.d-sm-none .d-md-block`?**

Problems on line 19 and 86

Link to code: https://plnkr.co/edit/fEnwv72F5k0832PvU6bD?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want mobile screens, you should use `col-12`, `col-sm-12` is for landscape phones; and you are including the dot in the class name, it should be `d-none` or `d-md-block`... There are also some other issues on your HTML structure; columns should be direct children of `row`; you have another div between the `row` and columns

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

I made some fixes to the structure you had regarding `row` and `columns`; I also removed the set width you had on the cards which prevented them to use the full width; also fixed the class names for display that you were using, check it out

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20348%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_169b97cc54a%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A17pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_169b97cc54a%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22116.71875%22%20y%3D%22120.15%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
          data-holder-rendered="true" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20348%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_169b97cc54a%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A17pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_169b97cc54a%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22116.71875%22%20y%3D%22120.15%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
          data-holder-rendered="true" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20348%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_169b97cc54a%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A17pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_169b97cc54a%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22116.71875%22%20y%3D%22120.15%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
          data-holder-rendered="true" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 d-none d-md-block">
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&bg=55595c&fg=eceeef&text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20348%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_169b97cc54a%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A17pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_169b97cc54a%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22116.71875%22%20y%3D%22120.15%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
          data-holder-rendered="true" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these guide**

1. Check your card, you are adding an inline style `style="width: 18rem;"` remove that and also remove the `<div class="mb-3">` wrapper
2. Add `mb-3` to the next `div` wrapper class="col-sm-12 col-md-3`mb-3`" instead, the card expands should work.
3. Replace `col-sm-12` with `col-12`